# What IDE can successfully change the type of all variables from QSharedPointer to boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, refactoring

Today I tried to change the type of all smart pointers of type QSharedPointer in a project of 100+ files to boost::shared_ptr.

I approached this problem with sed and grep, but what looked easy first, turned out to be quite a nightmare, because while QSharedPointer has only clear and data, boost::shared_ptr uses reset and get respectively. Replacing those turned out to also replace the clear of numerous lists and strings, and the data() of byte arrays.

Is there an IDE that can do this job automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You could do what Drew Dormann suggests with Qt Creator as well, and its free, if you don't already have it. Just rightclick on the `clear()` and `data()` methods of a `QSharedPointer` instance, select Refactor - Rename symbol under cursor, and replace with the methods for `boost::shared_ptr`

Keep in mind the Creator refactoring tool, at least on windows, will go out of your project and offer to refactor the Qt library headers as well, so you should uncheck those from the list.

After you replace all the calls you can rename `QSharedPointer` to `boost::shared_ptr` type name and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is an add-on for Visual Studio that has a free trial period.

That tool includes a "rename this member function", which you could use on the two `QSharedPointer` members before *sed-grepping* the name of the type itself.